# Published App with Google Fitness API

Tags: android

I developed and published an android mobile App on Google Play store. 
My App has a Google Fit Api and works perfectly, when I test it. But when downloaded by a user from the Playstore, it will not move beyond the introduction screen that asks them to select their Google account.... I can only assume that there are steps I need to follow to prepare the app for release, besides the normal apk signing and creating credentials. To be specific, it does not show the request permission screen, even though all the permissions are specified in the Manifesto. It's a fitness app with an Sql database and every aspect of the app works exactly as expected, accept for the step counter. Can someone point me to specific guidelines to follow or send me a link with steps to follow at the publishing phase.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since this app is already published, the request for steps in the "publishing phase" doesn't make sense. Can you narrow down the search for information?

Comment: At this stage, I need to unpublished or update it with the same APK, but new and higher version than the current one. I can still pull it off, well I need to and implement the changes I may have missed when I tried to publish it the first time. I can't keep it in the store if it's not functioning well.